# animation nodes error: node editor red outline and render error

Tags: animation, node-editor, add-on, animation-nodes

im trying to use animation nodes addon. here is an image of my nodes. I am trying to make the animation nodes control the colour of the cube but when I eye-drop the cube i get a red outline around my nodes and the render result isn't right. (see picture) can someone please explain what im doing wrong? im new to this addon

[image] I eye-drop